# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) error occurs when I just try to open a IE browser

Tags: ruby, watir

I have written the following the code,

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'www.google.com'
```

When I am executing the above code, It throws the following error,

```
 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:195: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I am using RUBY 2.1.5 and WATIR 4.0.2, Is there any solution for this error?

Comment: if you comment this out the error disappears ?

Comment: I don't get you , which one I comment?

Comment: actually stack level too deep error occurs when you calling method inside another and it goes on. so which of your line produces this i am not sure.